# Android App _ D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Tags: java, android

My application had the `D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM` error with
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference"`

```
public void resultOnScreen(Bitmap bitmap){
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

   if (bitmap != null){
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   } else{

   }     
}
```

But like above, I don't do match thing. I would like to just show an image of Android.

Actually, bitmap has a value. Before the `ImageView` line, it was working. How can I resolve that issue?

Comment: From where are you calling this method?

Comment: On which activity are you calling the method? It seems like the activity itself is null.

Comment: This method is calling from MainActivity on Android app.

Comment: And Bitmap is received from the other class that is within the same package.

Comment: At this method, I would like to show the bitmap that came from the other class on the Android screen.